# MYSQL split date string to standard format

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime

This is my first post on the forums.

I would like your help to have `MySQL` to convert from `20200416174119Z` to `2020-04-16 17:41:19`.

Thank you in advance for providing light to the world.

Best regards,

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried, if you get errors, if you have a specific problem... Usually asking for people to do your work/homework doesn't result in a response or a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback My apologies, I'm not skilled in MySQL beside doing basic select, update and delete queries.  Tried googling but no luck. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Well, after several for days of frustration, and failed attempts, here is a code that can help someone that is trying to do this

SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(date,1,4),'-',SUBSTR(date,5,2),'-',SUBSTR(date,7,2),' ',SUBSTR(date,9,2),':',SUBSTR(date,11,2),':',SUBSTR(date,13,2))